# Salary deferred to next month

Tags: software-industry, salary, india

I joined this company on 10th feb. The company remits salary to only three banks and I didn't have my a/c with any of those so I had to open a new a/c. However I forgot to share my new bank a/c details with the company until today when I got a mail from payroll asking for my bank a/c details. Now due to the delay they are saying they will credit the salary at the end of next month only.

I had to move to a new city for this job and I will have fixed expenses like rent to meet which I told to HR and payroll but they said they can't help. Is there any way to solve this issue other than borrowing from friends or family?

I asked the person from payroll to write a cheque instead but he said "They don't do cheque business here".

This is a multinational organization with around 500 employees.

Comment: Can you clarify your jurisdiction? Some places have laws about how quickly you must be paid.

Comment: you should add the country to your questions, because there might be legal stuff involved in the answer.

Comment: Have you asked them to write a check for you?

Comment: @sf02 I did but verbally and they declined should I put it on mail?

Comment: Yes you should put it in writing, it always helps to have a paper trail in case you need to make a legal argument later.

Comment: Did you try to involve your manager? Payroll might be more accommodating if your manager backs you up.

Comment: @perenniallydisappointed I did not as he is on leave and will be back next week. But I discussed this with team lead he asked to contact payroll and HR which I did.

Comment: Ask for an advance on your pay. Most companies do this from time to time for various reasons and it is handled differently from an out of sync pay check.

Comment: @Brian he mentions already talking to HR/payroll about the issue and they didn't help. I don't have an answer, but I know i would have trouble working if I wasn't getting paid. Especially if bills were coming up.

Comment: I VTC as this directly regards to that company policies, and as they are sizeable company and there is partial OP fault here, I imagine they are allowed to do this by law. Best advice I can give @Stupid_Intern is to keep pressing your boss once he is back to help out.

Comment: I can promise you I would find another job... The basic idea is you work for money. They can do a bank transfer to any bank account in the world - banks use ISBN codes for exactly that resaon.

Comment: @SolarMike That's not universally true in every part of the world, and doing so may incur notable fees.

Comment: Hopefully, you have learned a lesson, that you should submit required paperwork before it's due.  If you don't know when the paperwork is due, you need to ask, and find out an answer the same day.  If you started on the 10th, you should have been aware when the paperwork was due, the day you started.

Comment: @SolarMike People work for money, and that's why it is important to know the process by which you get paid and follow it properly. By "forgetting" to inform his employer about his bank account before the deadline, OP has clearly indicated that getting his salary on time was not one of his top priorities at this job.

Comment: @UchihaMadara I know people work for money - that’s why I stated that clearly....

Comment: If I was you, I would insist they pay it soon to my boss/HR/.. If they are not willing to help you, start looking for another job.

Comment: @SolarMike Right, I wasn't disagreeing with you. I was adding on to your point, because the OP doesn't seem to get it. He seems to think he is entitled to demand his employer jump through additional hoops after he neglected to follow the process clearly communicated to him in advance. He has a better chance if he requests his employer politely for an alternative than making demands like writing a cheque. "Yeah, I forgot to tell you my bank account number until you reminded me again even though I knew it was important. No big deal, just write a cheque."

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any way to solve this issue other than borrowing from friends
>   or family?
>
> I asked the person from payroll to write a check instead but he said
>   "They don't do check business here".

You could try bypassing Payroll and making your plea to your boss or to someone higher up.

Payroll might not be able to cut a check, but perhaps Accounts Payable could.

It probably won't help. Most likely you'll have to wait. But it probably won't hurt to try.

Comment: But is it not that the HR already mentioned there's no other way?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere There you go.

Comment: +1 Tell your manager you are in a serious bind because you need your pay to relocate.Ask them to arrange a salary advance for you, after you explain the payroll shenanigans.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escalate this issue.

First to your boss, and then to the boss of the HR person/payroll person.

Aside from that, you should also contact your labour commissioner and see what they say. https://clc.gov.in/clc/

In your country, the labour commissioner is in charge of recovering late wages/unpaid wages.

Comment: Yea great way for a 3 week old employee to make an impression, especially when it was due to his own f up.

Comment: @Jack, I completely disagree. This is actually a super common issue with new employees and this is why payrolls will often cut employees a check for the first month of work. And if they're not competent enough to cut a check, I'm sorry, but they don't deserve to be in business at all. It's really not that hard to cut a check.

Comment: Reporting your employer to the Labour Commission?

Comment: @Jack, Not necessarily. Like I said already, I think he should just talk to them "and see what they say."

Answer (score 0):

> *Now due to delay they are saying they will credit the salary at the end of next month only.*

Seems to be a standard process in India.

> *I had to move to new city for this job and I will have fixed expense like rent to meet which I told to HR and payroll but they said they can't help.*

Not supposed to be their problem and they are not obliged to entertain any request in this regard. You can request, you cannot expect / demand. Unless you have a very strong reason to believe that HR is not knowledgeable or is lying - that's probably the end of road of this discussion.

> *Is there any way to solve this issue other than borrowing from friends or family?*

As per the current situation, official response is no. Unless the HR forgot to mention / did not mention a process for advance payment of salary - there does not seem to be another way - check your company handbook again.

Comment: @Stupid_Intern I'm sorry, what this has to do anything with a country?

Comment: Everything. It tells about the company the people and their processes.

Comment: @AriKari India's funds transfer is the best in the world. http://businessnewsthisweek.com/business/indias-imps-rated-as-worlds-best-real-time-money-transfer-platform/ So, stop with the bigotry. Most companies don't even have a cheque book, because paying employee salaries is completely automated. It is entirely the OP's fault if he thought the company would transfer his salary to a bank account that he "forgot" to tell them about.

Comment: @Stupid_Intern Well, it does. There is a balance here: One employee having to do 15 minutes extra work, or one employee without money for a month. What's more important? You clearly saw what's more important where you work. Working in the UK, I think if at _any_ company that I worked for HR or payroll refused to give you your money in this situation, my boss would have ripped them to pieces, plus it would be illegal.

Comment: @gnasher729 ... and that's what most companies in India do as well. I never said anything about the OP taking a loan from the company, so I don't understand how you came to the conclusion that I find it "normal". OP needs to *ask* for the loan. If he is working, he is most likely an adult, and the company shouldn't have to tell him how to fix his mistakes and handle his money matters. The company clearly told him on the 10th he needs to open a bank account with one of 3 banks, and tell them his account number by a certain date. The company isn't "despicable" if the OP "forgets" to do that.

Comment: Sure, legally it might not be the company's problem, but any company that is so inflexible and callous that it can't find a way to not have an employee go without salary for a month is not one worth working at.

Answer (score -1):

## If your work isn’t willing to budge, consider getting a short-term loan from a lender.

I’m not certain about India, but in many Western countries there are predatory loan companies that give short-term loans (on the order of a few weeks) in exchange for fees that amount to a ruinous interest rate. They’re often thought of as being exploitative towards the poor, but in your case, they might be helpful as long as you only use their services to cover your bills once and you don’t become reliant on their services.

Obviously, this should be your last resort, if you can’t get your work to pay you and you can’t get the money any other way. It’s not a very good option, but it’s probably better than missing rent payments and becoming homeless.

Comment: Lord no, OP should do literally anything else instead.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul It’d be better than becoming homeless due to missing rent payments. Obviously a last resort, though.

Comment: You won't become homeless for one late rent payment, that's plain rubbish. Borrow from friends, pawn stuff, sell stuff, work nights at fast food joint. Anything but fall into hands of predatory lenders.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul OP lives in India, where a significant chunk of the population are impoverished farmers. It’s entirely possible he doesn’t have any stuff to sell, or friends to borrow money from.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Also, a quick Google search for rental laws in India says that you can be evicted if a rental payment is 15 days overdue- so you can be evicted for missing one rent payment there.

Comment: Credit card, if the OP  has one, would be much better option than a pay day loan (shark). Or parents, friends, family. Heck, even the pawn shop would probably be better